# Modal - keep default value

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a modal using Bootstrap and React.

Within it, I have a dropdown, which has an empty element as its first option:

```
<select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelectCat}>
    <option disabled selected></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
```

[image]

If I select an option:

[image]

and than if I close the modal, when I open it I get the previously selected option as my default.

[image]

How can make it such that the empty option is the default every time I open the modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the event of closing the modal, fire a method that resets the selection of the drop-down list.

Comment: Or when you first display it

Comment: @JuanMendes When it is first displayed, it already displays the blank default value.

Comment: I mean every time you display it